# How to replace a pattern from a string of values in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace a pattern (",,") from a list of values in column of a Dataframe.

```
final['Type']=final['Type'].replace(",,","")
```

But, it is not working and not replacing any values from my `Type` column

But when i try to replace for a particular row., It is working.

For example:

```
final['Type'][1].replace(",,","")

#this is working and replacing the string
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please post a sample of your input data and ideally the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
final['Type'] = final['Type'].str.replace(',,','')
```

your code only works when the values exactly match.